# How to overwrite an image file in c++

Tags: c++, image, fstream

**Complete Edit:**
I am creating an image file from stream from smart card reader. After reading, file is being created successfully. What i need to add, when creating file, if file under same name exist, is to be overwritten, since i don't want bunch of files clogging up. OS is win10 x64.

Stream is `unsigned char` array. Tried setting different flags, it was no go.

Trying outright deleting it, also doesn't work. It asks for admin rights. But i can't allow for prompt. It's project directory, so path is not a problem.

Can image deleted/overwritten without prompts after it's being found, before new one is being created from stream?

Type of a stream as per `typeid(stuff).name()` is:

```
    //char * __ptr64
    cout << "Type1: " << typeid(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&personPortrait.portrait)).name() << endl;
    //unsigned char (* __ptr64)[7700]
    cout << "Type2: " << typeid((&personPortrait.portrait)).name() << endl;
    //unsigned char [7700]
    cout << "Type3: " << typeid(personPortrait.portrait).name() << endl;
```

My code:

```
    fstream avatar;
    avatar.open(fileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    avatar.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&personPortrait.portrait), personPortrait.portraitSize); // or with recent C++: reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>
    avatar.close();
```

It creates file if it doesn't exists in directory, but does not overwrite if file already exist(which i need it to do).

Comment: So, you are showing a working code, but you question is about a not working code, that is not shown?

Comment: did you try std::ios::out instead of std::ios::app? The file probably can't be removed because it is still being used by a process

Comment: @273K It needs to overwrite image if present in directory. Now doesn't save newly added image if another card is inserted and read.

Comment: @Mayfair Tried it. It does the same. Doesn't overwrite, which is what i need.

Comment: @Mayfair That the only line where file is being written or mentioned for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc` as flags for `::open`. You should also check if the process has sufficient rights to write to the created file.

Comment: Tried it. Doesnt work. Need rights, but i need to executed in background without prompt. Nevermind, i am going to handle it different way.